# Zodiac sign with Python using dict

Tags: python

could u please help, it least the beginning, where i need to start.
the task is

```
Enter the month number (1-12) of your date of birth: 7 (for example)
Enter the number of your date of birth: 4
Your zodiac sign: Aries

zodiac = {
    "aries": '21.03-20.04',
    "taurus": '21.04-21.05',
    "gemini": '22.05-21.06',
    "cancer": '22.06-22.07',
    "lio": '23.07-22.08',
    "virgo": '23.08-23.09',
    "libra": '24.09-23.10',
    "scorpio": '24.10-22.11',
    "sagittarius": '23.11-21.12',
    "capricorn": '22.12-20.01',
    "aquarius": '21.01-18.02',
    "pisces": '19.02-20.03',
}
```

To check the validity of the date, i will also need another dictionary, with a max. number of days per month

i did this task with if/elif - its ok for me, but using dict....a little problem

Comment: You should share a [mre] of your attempt

Comment: I suggest taking a step back and describe in words what steps you would take to solve this yourself.

Comment: `zodiac["pisces"]` gives you `'19.02-20.03'` and from there you can `'19.02-20.03'.split("-")` to get a pair of data points that you can parse into dates....

Answer (score 1):

I've put the max number of days per month as another dictionary. One way you can achieve this:

```
zodiac = {
    "aries": '21.03-20.04',
    "taurus": '21.04-21.05',
    "gemini": '22.05-21.06',
    "cancer": '22.06-22.07',
    "lio": '23.07-22.08',
    "virgo": '23.08-23.09',
    "libra": '24.09-23.10',
    "scorpio": '24.10-22.11',
    "sagittarius": '23.11-21.12',
    "capricorn": '22.12-20.01',
    "aquarius": '21.01-18.02',
    "pisces": '19.02-20.03',
}

month_days = {
    1 : 31,
    2 : 28,
    3 : 31,
    4 : 30,
    5:31,
    6:30,
    7:31,
    8:31,
    9:30,
    10:31,
    11:30,
    12:31
}

month = input("Enter the month number (1-12) of your date of birth:")
day = input("Enter the number of your date of birth:")

def convert_to_days(month, d):
    days = 0
    for i in range(1,int(month)):
        days += d[i]
    return days

user_zodiac = ""

for item in zodiac.items():
    limits = item[1].split("-")
    day_and_month = [limit.split(".") for limit in limits]

    if (int(day_and_month[0][0].lstrip("0"))+convert_to_days(int(day_and_month[0][1].lstrip("0")), month_days)) \
        <= int(day) + convert_to_days(month, month_days) <= \
        (int(day_and_month[1][0].lstrip("0"))+convert_to_days(int(day_and_month[1][1].lstrip("0")), month_days)):
        user_zodiac = item[0]
        break


if user_zodiac == "":
    user_zodiac = "capricorn"

print(f"Your zodiac sign is {user_zodiac}")
```

Essentially what we do is convert the months into days (i.e. maximum of 365 for 31.12) and check if the entered month and day falls between certain ranges.

Note that since you are entering in month number first and date second, a person with a birthday on July 4th has the sign of Cancer, not Aries, which would be if you had a birthday on April 7th.

**Output:**

```
Enter the month number (1-12) of your date of birth:7
Enter the number of your date of birth:4
Your zodiac sign is cancer

Enter the month number (1-12) of your date of birth:11
Enter the number of your date of birth:22
Your zodiac sign is scorpio

Enter the month number (1-12) of your date of birth:2
Enter the number of your date of birth:14
Your zodiac sign is aquarius
```

Comment: Thank you a lot))) if truly i thought i can do it without def)

Comment: by the way, i tried to put month 1 and it does not work....(

Comment: @kATEPETROVA What was your exact input?

Comment: 1 and 1, then i tried 01 and 01

Comment: @kATEPETROVA I found there was an issue with Capricorn where this math doesn't work (because we loop over from 365 back to 0, so the number isn't in between the ranges anymore. I will edit the code to make some more changes

Comment: @Kristina No problem! Be sure to click the check mark to accept the answer if this has solved your problem.